# What's the difference between the CMP and TST instructions in ARM?

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between these two instructions in ARM. From what I understand,

```
CMP R1, R2
```

Would perform the action R1-R2, but not store the result. It would then set flags in the status register such as N (negative, if R1

What I don't get is what TST does differently. In my notes it says that TST doesn't change the values of its operands.. but I thought CMP didn't either. How do the two instructions differ?

How is

```
CMP R1, R2
```

different to

```
TST R1, R2
```

? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TST R1, R2` computes the bitwise AND of `R1` and `R2` and then discards the result while `CMP R1, R2` subtracts the two.  `TST` is mainly useful on ARM for finding out if a given bit is set in a number.  For example, to check if `R1` is odd, you might do:

```
TST R1, #1    @ is R1 odd?
```

This sets the Z flags to 0 iff `R1` is odd.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. How does TST calculate the bitwise AND and use its result though? For example if R1 held #100, what would TST R1, #1 do? Would it just perform and AND on the least significant bit of R1 with #1 and ignore the rest?

Comment: @user43712 It performs the same calculation as `AND`, i.e. each bit in the first argument is ANDed with the corresponding bit in the second argument.  Immediates are converted to 32 bit integers, just like with every other instruction.  `#1` is the same as `#0x00000001` if that helps you.

Comment: an AND based compare is not exclusive to arm nor useful only to arm.  the "on ARM" part of your statement doesnt make sense...

Comment: Ahh thank you, yes that clears things up. One final related question - how are flags set if all we get is a number the same length as the longest operand as the result of TST? You mentioned in the test for odd numbers the Z flag is set if the least significant bit of R1 is equal to 1. How is the flag set?

Comment: @old_timer On x86, `test` is also commonly used to compare a register with zero due to its shorter instruction encoding; this usage is uncommon on ARM though as `cmp r0, #0` is just as long as `tst r0, r0`.

Comment: @user43712 The Z flag is set according to whether the result is zero, the C flag is left unchanged but may be affected if the second operand contains a shift.  The V flag is left unchanged.  The S flag is set according to the most significant bit of the result (i.e. is set if the result is negative).

Comment: you could add some more text to explain that then.  tst r1,r1 vs cmp r1,0, etc...and why on arm it is a wash but not on other platforms.  less confusion...

Comment: @GabrielRevier: Please post these links as comments and don't add them to the answer.  I do not endorse this resource as I have not checked its correctness.

Comment: @old_timer Feel free to do so!  I think this might just confuse OP.

Comment: I'll do my best to wrap my head around anyone's answer. Hearing it explained from multiple people could be very useful for me and future readers with the same question. I encourage anyone to reply with an answer even if it is a little beyond my scope of understanding. Thanks again for your help everyone :)

Comment: @user43712 It's my pleasure.

Comment: It sets Z flag to 1 if the result of AND operation is zero. And it is zero for even numbers (2, 4, 6, ...) - with LSB bit 0. Here is a short ARM ASM to verify https://cpulator.01xz.net/?sys=arm&loadasm=share/s33LHiT.s Zero flag on ARM is bit 30 in cpsr register.