# Clarity About TST Instruction - ARM Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, arm, armv6

So here I have the following code (ARMv6 assembly):

```
wait$: 
    ldr r2,[r0,#24] //read 32 bits from addr + 24 in r0 and store in r2
    tst r2,#0x80000000 //????
    bne wait$
```

I understand all of the lines other than the `tst` instruction. I have done some research online and the best definition I could find was:

> Test if a register is zero or minus. Perform a logical AND between a register and itself.

I had some trouble understanding what it meant so I then tried to make the C equivalent to an `tst` instruction and this is what I got:

```
if(valRead & 0x80000000 != 0){}
```

The code above does not seems to be working. What is an  easier to understand definition of `tst` and what is the equivalent to it in C?

Comment: This clarify your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54131662/whats-the-difference-between-the-cmp-and-tst-instructions-in-arm

Comment: @Frankie_C pretty much the same definition as the one I have got

Comment: TST doesn't **perform a logical AND between a register and itself**, but with the second operand and sets the zero flag accordingly with result. The and with itself is used to check for zero result. The C definition is valid, even removing the `!=0` part. If it doesn't work for you check if `ValRead` is the same as `ldr r2,[r0,#24]`.

Comment: `volatile int *ptr = /*whatever is in r0*/; while (ptr[6] < 0);`

Comment: The C code doesn't work because your parentheses are wrong.  `!=` binds tighter than `&` in C.  You need to write `if ((valRead & 0x80000000) != 0)` or just `if (valRead & 0x80000000)` for this to work.

Comment: while((*u32ptr)<0) continue;

Comment: while(((*u32ptr)&0x80000000)!=0) continue;

Comment: it is not an if it is a while

Comment: arm has quite clearly documented this instruction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is an easier to understand definition of `tst` and what is the equivalent to it in C?

**Some background**

There is no equivalent in C because higher-level languages work differently than a CPU with "status registers" (such as ARM or x86):

In high-level languages like C or C++, conditional code execution can be done directly:

```
if(a < b) ...
```

On a CPU with a "status register", conditional code execution is done in two steps:

- In the first step, you perform some calculation (such as `a-b`).
  In the so-called "status register" the CPU stores some "relevant" information (e.g. the sign) about the result.
- In the second step, the actual conditional code execution is done.
  This can only be done depending on the information in the "status register".

A simplified example:

The operation `if(a < b) ...` could be performed the following way on a CPU with a "status register":

```
/* Subtract b from a */
c = a - b;
/* (a < b) means that (a - b) is negative */
if(status.last_result_was_negative) ...
```

... however, the result of the operation (`c` in the example) is not needed.

**The** `TST` **and** `CMP` **instructions**

To perform an `if(...)` operation, two operations are often needed:

- A subtraction:
  it is needed for `==`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` and `!=`.
- An AND operation:
  it is needed to check if some bit(s) in a value is (are) set:
  `if(a & 0x8000) ...`

... and in both cases, the result of the operation (the difference or the result of the AND operation) is not needed.

For this reason, there are two instructions (`CMP` and `TST`) that perform an operation (`CMP` performs a subtraction and `TST` performs an AND operation) but discard the result:

The `TST` operation performs an AND operation, sets the information in the "status register" according to the result but it discards the actual result.

This makes sense in lines like `if(a & 0xF000) ...` where you are only interested in that the "status register" holds the information if the result of the operation `a & 0xF000` was zero or not, but you are not interested in the actual result of `a & 0xF000`.

> ```
> if(valRead & 0x80000000 != 0){}
> ```

You need brackets:

```
if((valRead & 0x80000000) != 0){}
```

Otherwise the compiler understands:

```
if(valRead & (0x80000000 != 0)){}
```

... which is the same as:

```
if((valRead & 1) != 0){}
```